# Wifi keeps disconnecting on hp

Tags: 16.04

My WiFi does not disconnect. Only the connectivity to Internet keeps dropping.

I have tried at the different locations (different WiFi), the problem is same. Any point of time I get disconnected from Internet (WiFi shows connected to the network). After I reboot it works fine. Disconnecting and connecting to WiFi again does not help.

Comment: sounds like hardware problems rather than Ubuntu problems.  have you ruled out a hardware issue?